# Error: Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, error-handling, runtime-error

Here is my code, I dont understand why am I getting this error, I even used the command npm update but nothing seems to be working.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const File = require('../models/file');
const User = require('../app');

router.get('/:uuid_d', async (req, res) => {
 // Extract link and get file from storage send download stream
 const file = await File.findOne({ uuid_d: req.params.uuid_d });
 const user = await User.findOne({ googleId: req.body.guploadBy});
 // Link expired
 if(!file) {
      return res.render('download', { error: 'Nothing Found'});
 }

 const response = await file.save();
 const response2 = await user.save();
 const filePath = `${__dirname}/../${file.path}`;
 file.downloads++;
 var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
file.lastClick = today;
 file.save();

user.downloads++;
user.save();

 res.download(filePath);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my error

node:9868) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
at C:\Users\Puneet\Documents\Dream Project\routes\download.js:8:26
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:9868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9868) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Does the app.js file export a function called findOne? According to the error it doesn't. Shouldn't by any chance this `const User = require('../app');` be `const User = require('../models/user');`?? I mean the file model is in `/models/file` so it would make a lot of sense to have user model also in the models folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this **solved my problem**:

1. `yarn remove mongoose` or `npm uninstall mongoose --save`
2. `yarn add mongoose` or `npm install mongoose --save`